# How should I configure Nginx to proxy to a URL passed by parameter?

Tags: nginx, proxy, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get access to media files (images, videos) sitting behind an OAuth2 authentication.

In order to access the resource I need to add a custom Authorization Bearer token to the request, so I can't use a simple rewrite (well, as far as I know at least).

It cannot be done via plain HTML (say `img` or `video` tag) so I'm considering to have Nginx proxying the queries to the final server.

Each of the media resources would be loaded via a `/proxy` path, with a `token` parameter (for authentication) and `url` for the actual resource to load.

Sample URL:

```
http://myserver.com/proxy/?token=12345&url=http://protectedserver.com/custompath/asset
```

This is what I came up with but I am not quite sure how to configure the `proxy_pass` directive since I need it to proxy to the `$url` variable specifically. I do not need to proxy the path (which would be empty anyway).

```
location /proxy/ {
  if ($arg_token ~ "^$") { return 404; }
  if ($arg_url ~ "^$") { return 404; }
  set $url $arg_url;
  proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer $arg_token";
  set $args "";
  #proxy_pass $url;
}
```

*Note*: this will be run in a closed environment and only specific machines (kiosks with limited interaction) will be able to access the page so I'm not concerned about a potential leak of the auth token.

I noticed a similar question on ServerFault, but no one had an answer to that:
https://serverfault.com/questions/671991/nginx-proxy-pass-url-from-get-argument

I'm looking for a config setting to make it work or a viable alternative solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a correct configuration for my problem:

```
location /proxy/ {
  if ($arg_token ~ "^$") { return 404; }
  if ($arg_url ~ "^$") { return 404; }

  set $url $arg_url;
  set $token $arg_token;
  set $args "";

  # IMPORTANT, this is required when using dynamic proxy pass
  # You can alternatively use any DNS resolver under your control
  resolver 8.8.8.8;

  proxy_pass $url;
  proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer $token";
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```